# Laravel - Service Provider : Class not found

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider

I started a project on Laravel 5.4 today and got a ServiceProvider problem. 
Here my service provider :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class WizamProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //die('YESSS');
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
      $this->app->bind('Wizam\Test', function()
      {
        if(class_exists("Domains\Domomat\Test"))
          return new \Domains\Domomat\Test;
        else
          return new \Core\Classes\Test;
      });
    }
}
```

I added this provider into config/app.php (`App\Providers\WizamProvider::class`), dump my autoloader like twenty times, clear cache, clear config. Nothing happened.

Here my route :

```
Route::get('/sub', function()
{
  $test = new \Wizam\Test();
  echo $test->render();
});
```

When I go to '/sub', I got `Class 'Wizam\Test' not found`. I cannot see my error, can you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you setup autoloading for your classes in your `composer.json`? Also, if you want to use the container call it like this instead: `app(\Wizam\Test::class)`

Comment: For existing classes yes ! I didn't do it for \Wizam because it doesn't technically exist.

Comment: THANK YOU !! `app(\Wizam\Test::class)` works just fine !!!

Answer (score 0):

To use the container you cannot instantiate using the new command, you can either inject it through the constructor

```
__constructor(\Wizam\Test $test)
{
}
```

or using the app(\Wizam\Test::class) I believe is the other way to do it as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If someone once will get error saying that your interface not found ('class not found'), during making service provider closure, make sure your interface and class located in app/ folder. It took a lot of time fixing this. Have a nice day.
P.S. answer is not related to topic, but this page is first I found when I started to google the solution, so I beg you leave this here.